# How can i be sure i'm using EC2-VPC instead of Classic?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-rds, amazon-vpc

Im new to aws so i need a bit of help, i work in a very small IT firm and we're starting to use aws again (they only used azure). The account is both Classic and VPC enabled and i need some help to make sure i won't lose the instances i've created. I created the instances and rds's last year and someone told me that already means its in a VPC. But apart from that, is there any other way to make sure they're already in a VPC and won't be deleted?   (I tried using the script but it's too complicated to do with my current knowledge)

Thank you for your patience.

Comment: Run the [EC2 Classic Resource Finder](https://github.com/aws-samples/ec2-classic-resource-finder) and check the CSV files it produces.

Comment: What do you mean "ensure that they won't be deleted"?